# How can i send docusign envelop to multiple recipient when first recipient will sign than second recipient will receive doc?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API for an electronic sign.
How can I implement this when the first recipient views and signs the document, and then the second recipient receives an email to sign the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Routing Order](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=ulp1643236876813&topicId=kcb1578456479440.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301=) is what you use for this.

If you set it like this:

First recipient "1"
Second recipient "2"

Then they sign in the order you request, just change the `routing_order` in your code to ensure it's routed in the order you want.

Comment: Can you provide any example code @Inbar Gazit

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/ab381aa83ff8ae2d0d207c6149c38e6f7c3677ae/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/SMSDeliveryService.php#L75

Comment: You will have to change it to fit your scenario, but you can get the idea